# Freelance trading of products in India

Tags: india, small-business, non-resident, saudi-arabia

I am an Non Resident Indian living in Saudi Arabia. I have a query for starting freelance  trading of products in India. Is it possible for me to trade without a license or registration with the Indian government? The trading will be done through the bank accounts of both India and Saudi Arabia. Please do advise me to get a clear picture for business in India.

Comment: That would depend on the products being traded and the amount, whether the goods are physical goods etc.

Comment: Mr. Dheer, The items being traded are physical and would be below RS. 1500 including profits.

Answer (score 1):

For most goods there is no license required, unless you are trading in restricted goods. Remittance need to be routed via banks and they should comply with FMEA. Your Bank or a qualified CA can guide you.